# Light Web Server with no installation required

Tags: windows-10, webserver

I'm developing a rather simple Web Page that provides some Powerpoint-like functionality (I mean, much less that Powerpoint but something similar to Powerpoint "Show").

This application needs to be as portable as possible and hence it should be possible to deploy it into an external storage (e.g. memory stick or external disk) such that, upon connecting the storage to a computer (Windows 10-11 only), it would be possible to execute a small script that would:

- Run the Web Server,
- Run the default browser with the index.html file (again, deployed within the external storage).

A second script will also be available to stop any process (e.g. Web Server). I had a look at Tiny-Web but, unfortunately, they provide a rather old version of the product and zero support (I posted a YES/NO question and they refused to answer).

Comment: I have done this multiple times with just raw HTML and jQuery --  Create a single (index.html) page app, and If you need back-end processing, build yourself an API and connect it with it remotely.  There are many advantages to this approach.  One is that you can update your API and everyone who has the mobile app will be updated.  You can also use iFrame and other tools to help with the items you want to display.  Basically create a web view and do the heavy lifting elsewhere.  No need for a web server -- index.html will open on any browser.

Comment: Thank you @Zak for your reply. I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. My application uses only Bootstrap and Font Awesome as the sole external libraries (i.e. no JQuery). When opening the index file without the VS-Code's server, I get errors: CORS when attempting to load Bootstrap's min.css and ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when attempting to load other files. Could you provide some additional details on how to resolve these? Also, take into account that the solution will be ran from external storage (meaning, not necessarily the same drive letter). Thanks.

Comment: Always load Bootstrap and FontAwesome from their CDNs .. You won't get a CORS error: -- [BootStrap](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap) and [Font Awesome](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) -- Be sure to pick the correct versions .. And click the `</>` icon .. It will copy the `<script`> and `<link>` tags to your clipboard.  Also as BS and FA release updates, you don't have to worry about re-distributing your app -- The beauty of using a CDN.

Comment: Thank you @Zak for your suggestion. I tried going in that direction but it makes things too complex because the application I'm developing is aimed to support loading (potentially) thousands of media files from a dynamic set of sub-folders. Setting aside the complexity of using a light-weight Web server, once I have such task completed the remaining development, use and maintenance becomes straightforward. Do you happen to know of any such simple server I could use? Thanks again.